# Dropdown selection creating dynamic input types

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have three options in a dropdown in html.Now on selecting each one of the option in dropdown i want different input types to be created dynamically.

Firstly here are the options in dropdown :

```
<select  name="choicetosearch">

    <option value="None" style="display:none;">
        ---None---
    </option>

    <option value="searchName">
        Notification Sender
    </option>

    <option value="searchType">
        Notification Type  
    </option>

    <option value="searchDate">
        Notification Date  
    </option>

    </select>
```

Now, on selecting `Notification Sender` I want **a textbox** to be displayed.

On selecting `Notification Type` I want that **two checkboxes** should be shown.

On selecting `Notification Date` I want **two date type input fields** to be shown.

How this can be done?Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to learn some javascript since you didn't even provide any attemts to solve this problem.
Anyway, you need to create the fields you want to show/hide depending on the select box in your html markup and hide them via css. Afterwards you have to use an on change js event on your selectbox and check for the selected option. you now can hide/show the boxes you need.

Check this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Wvej/)

JS:

```
$('.search-select').on('change', function(){
  $('.search-inputs').children().hide();
  var classn =$(this).find(":selected").val();
  $('.'+classn).show();
})
```

HTML:

```
<select class="search-select" name="choicetosearch">

<option value="None">
    ---None---
</option>

<option value="searchName">
    Notification Sender
</option>

<option value="searchType">
    Notification Type  
</option>

<option value="searchDate">
    Notification Date  
</option>
</select>
<div class="search-inputs">
  <input class="searchName" type="text"></input>
  <input class="searchType" type="checkbox"></input>
  <input class="searchDate" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

Please make sure you refactor the classnames and values since I made this quickly.

Comment: The code works fine but the problem is on selecting second option i need two checkboxes and on selecting third option i need to textfields

Comment: And where is the problem? The code I provided is more than you can expect already. You can use it and create as many fields as you like. Just add a 2nd checkbox and wrap a div with the class searchType around it.. Same for the textfields. It's not like others should write the code for you at all. You havent even tried. it works for 1 so it works for more..

Answer (score 0):

Use '`onchange`' attribute of '`select`' element to track change of elements in `dropDown`.  To add an element, first generate it some thing like this -

```
var elem = '<b> hey</b>;
```

Then you can use `'append(elem)'` function in jQuery or `'appendChild(elem)'` in javascript.

I am not giving you the code so that you can try it, but if it still doesn't work, ping me, and I will share the code.

Here's a demo -

http://jsfiddle.net/RcfNL/2/

Adding to it, you can get the selected value of the drop down using this -

```
  var city_name = $('#city option:selected').text();
```

Based on the value, you can perform the required action.

Comment: Please provide me with code as am not able to do it since whole day..:(

Comment: @user3522121 wait then

Comment: this is not what was required

Comment: @user3522121 updated more based on your question. You should carry on from here because enough hints and pointers are given. And if it works for you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In onchange event of select create the elements dynamically using

```
 var dynElem = document.createElement('input');
        dynElem.type = 'text';
        dynElem.value = 'welcome';
```

then append the dynElem to Div using Javascript or Jquery like appendChild(dynElem) in javascript or append(dynElem) in jquery

Answer (score -1):

Please you can use this code snippet to your code block or test it first then use it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .searchName, .searchType, .searchDate{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createElement123(val){
         $('.search-inputs').children().hide();
         $('.' + val).show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="search-select" name="choicetosearch" onchange="createElement123(this.value)">
        <option value="None">---None---</option>
        <option value="searchName">Notification Sender</option>
        <option value="searchType">Notification Type</option>
        <option value="searchDate">Notification Date</option>
    </select>
    <div class="search-inputs">
        <input class="searchName" type="text" />
        <input class="searchType" type="checkbox" />
        <input class="searchDate" type="date" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that it will help to solve your problem. @Cheers

Comment: @user1509904 The code works fine but the problem is on selecting second option i need two checkboxes and on selecting third option i need to textfields

Comment: copy n pasting other answers shouldn't be the right way. downvote

Comment: you can just replace this to <div class="search-inputs">
        <input class="searchName" type="text">
        <div class="searchType">
        <input class="searchType1" type="checkbox">
        <input class="searchType1" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <input class="searchDate" type="text">
    </div>  instead of <div class="search-inputs">
        <input class="searchName" type="text" />
        <input class="searchType" type="checkbox" />
        <input class="searchDate" type="date" />
    </div>